# Solution for compiler warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I have the following code:

```
int cons_col()
{
for(int col =0; rx_state_== MAC_IDLE; col++)
return col;
}
```

It is like a counter that is supposed to return an integer when the condition rx_state_ == MAC_IDLE is met;
When I compile, I get the warning: control reaches end of non-void function.

Will this problem go away if add the following at the end of above function:

```
if (coll == 0)
return 0;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your function, as you intend it to work, simply returns 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code evaluates to this.

```
int cons_col()
{
    for( int col = 0; rx_state_ == MAC_IDLE; col++ )
    {
       return col;
       // "return" prevents this loop from finishing its first pass,
       // so "col++" (above) is NEVER called. 
    }
    // What happens here?  What int gets returned?
}
```

Note that this function will always **immediately** complete.

It does this:

- Sets an integer `col` to `0`.
- Checks **once** if `rx_state_` is `MAC_IDLE`.
- If it is, it returns `0`
- If it isn't, it gets to `// What happens here?`, and then reaches the end of the non-void function without returning anything.

From your description, you probably wanted something like this.

```
int cons_col()
{
    int col = 0;
    for( ; rx_state_ != MAC_IDLE; col++ )
    {
       // You may want some type of sleep() function here.
       // Counting as fast as possible will keep a CPU very busy
    }
    return col;
}
```

Comment: `Checks if 0 is also MAC_IDLE.`can you explain this  a bit more?

Comment: @Koushik Typo on my part! :-)

Comment: @DrewDormann: maybe paranoia on my part, but I always favor initializing variables at their declaration sites. `int col = 0; for(; rx_state_ ...`

Comment: @MatthieuM. I wasn't sure that that syntax was as obvious for new programmers... but you convinced me.